# How to make the output in the pipeline appear on the console when running pester tests?

Tags: powershell, unit-testing, pester

By default, the output in the pipeline is hidden,But sometimes I really want to know the output at that time.

Of course, I knew I could add additional commands, such as write-host or out-default.

But does Pester itself have a mechanism to make the output display properly?

I checked the help document and didn't find the relevant content, so I came here for help.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to write a custom `Should` wrapper (proxy) using [this technique](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65628204/7571258). The wrapper can write the pipeline objects to the console.

[Here is a complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65630650/7571258) of such a `Should` wrapper and how to override Pester's `Should`.

To apply it to your case, edit the `process{}` block of the wrapper like this:

```
process {
    try {
        # Here $_ is the current pipeline object
        Write-Host "Current test case input:`n$( $_ | Out-String )"
        
        # forward it to "process" block of original "Should"
        $steppablePipeline.Process( $_ )
    } catch {
        throw
    }
}
```