# Show content of hashtable when Pester test case fails

Tags: powershell, hashtable, pester

### Problem

When a `Hashtable` is used as input for `Should`, Pester outputs only the typename instead of the content:

```
Describe 'test' {
    It 'test case' {
        $ht = @{ foo = 21; bar = 42 }
        $ht | Should -BeNullOrEmpty
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Expected $null or empty, but got @(System.Collections.Hashtable).
```

Expected output like:

```
Expected $null or empty, but got @{ foo = 21; bar = 42 }.
```

### Cause

Looking at [Pester source](https://github.com/pester/Pester/blob/5bddc0291ae4a05b8a2325940eb1b8607b952cd0/src/Format.psm1#L119), the test input is formatted by private function `Format-Nicely`, which just casts to `String` if the value type is `Hashtable`. This boils down to calling `Hashtable::ToString()`, which just outputs the typename.

### Workaround

As a workaround I'm currently deriving a class from `Hashtable` that overrides the `ToString` method. Before passing the input to `Should`, I cast it to this custom class. This makes Pester call my overridden `ToString` method when formatting the test result.

```
BeforeAll {
    class MyHashTable : Hashtable {
        MyHashTable( $obj ) : base( $obj ) {}
        [string] ToString() { return $this | ConvertTo-Json }
    }
}

Describe 'test' {
    It 'test case' {
        $ht = @{ foo = 21; bar = 42 }
        [MyHashTable] $ht | Should -BeNullOrEmpty
    }
}
```

Now Pester outputs the `Hashtable` content in JSON format, which is good enough for me.

### Question

Is there a more elegant way to customize Pester output of `Hashtable`, which doesn't require me to change the code of each test case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A cleaner (albeit more lengthy) way than [my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65603732/7571258) is to write a wrapper function for `Should`.

Such a wrapper can be generated using `System.Management.Automation.ProxyCommand`, but it requires a little bit of stitchwork to generate it in a way that it works with the `dynamicparam` block of `Should`. For details see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65628204/7571258).

The wrappers `process` block is modified to cast the current pipeline object to a custom `Hashtable`-derived class that overrides the `.ToString()` method, before passing it to the `process` block of the original `Should` cmdlet.

```
class MyJsonHashTable : Hashtable {
    MyJsonHashTable ( $obj ) : base( $obj ) {}
    [string] ToString() { return $this | ConvertTo-Json }
}

Function MyShould {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(Position=0, ValueFromPipeline=$true, ValueFromRemainingArguments=$true)]
        [System.Object]
        ${ActualValue}
    )
    dynamicparam {
        try {
            $targetCmd = $ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.GetCommand('Pester\Should', [System.Management.Automation.CommandTypes]::Function, $PSBoundParameters)
            $dynamicParams = @($targetCmd.Parameters.GetEnumerator() | Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Where-Object { $_.Value.IsDynamic })
            if ($dynamicParams.Length -gt 0)
            {
                $paramDictionary = [Management.Automation.RuntimeDefinedParameterDictionary]::new()
                foreach ($param in $dynamicParams)
                {
                    $param = $param.Value
    
                    if(-not $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Parameters.ContainsKey($param.Name))
                    {
                        $dynParam = [Management.Automation.RuntimeDefinedParameter]::new($param.Name, $param.ParameterType, $param.Attributes)
                        $paramDictionary.Add($param.Name, $dynParam)
                    }
                }
    
                return $paramDictionary
            }
        } catch {
            throw
        }        
    }
    begin {
        try {
            $outBuffer = $null
            if ($PSBoundParameters.TryGetValue('OutBuffer', [ref]$outBuffer))
            {
                $PSBoundParameters['OutBuffer'] = 1
            }
    
            $wrappedCmd = $ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.GetCommand('Pester\Should', [System.Management.Automation.CommandTypes]::Function)
            $scriptCmd = {& $wrappedCmd @PSBoundParameters }
    
            $steppablePipeline = $scriptCmd.GetSteppablePipeline()
            $steppablePipeline.Begin($PSCmdlet)
        } catch {
            throw
        }
    
    }
    process {
        try {
            # In case input object is a Hashtable, cast it to our derived class to customize Pester output.
            $item = switch( $_ ) {
                { $_ -is [Hashtable] } { [MyJsonHashTable] $_ }
                default                { $_ }
            }
            $steppablePipeline.Process( $item )
        } catch {
            throw
        }        
    }
    end {        
        try {
            $steppablePipeline.End()
        } catch {
            throw
        }        
    }
}
```

To override Pesters `Should` by the wrapper, define a global alias like this:

```
Set-Alias Should MyShould -Force -Scope Global
```

And to restore the original `Should`:

```
Remove-Alias MyShould -Scope Global
```

**Notes:**

- I have also changed the argument of `GetCommand()` from `Should` to `Pester\Should` to avoid recursion due to the alias. Not sure if this is actually necessary though.
- A recent version of Pester is required. Failed with Pester 5.0.4 but tested successfully with Pester 5.1.1.

Answer (score 2):

Somewhat of a hack, override Pester's private `Format-Nicely` cmdlet by defining a global alias of the same name.

```
BeforeAll {
    InModuleScope Pester {
        # HACK: make private Pester cmdlet available for our custom override
        Export-ModuleMember Format-Nicely
    }

    function global:Format-NicelyCustom( $Value, [switch]$Pretty ) {
        if( $Value -is [Hashtable] ) {
            return $Value | ConvertTo-Json
        }
        # Call original cmdlet of Pester
        Pester\Format-Nicely $Value -Pretty:$Pretty
    }

    # Overrides Pesters Format-Nicely as global aliases have precedence over functions
    New-Alias -Name 'Format-Nicely' -Value 'Format-NicelyCustom' -Scope Global
}
```

This enables us to write test cases as usual:

```
Describe 'test' {
    It 'logs hashtable content' {
        $ht = @{ foo = 21; bar = 42 }
        $ht | Should -BeNullOrEmpty
    }   

    It 'logs other types regularly' {
        $true | Should -Be $false 
    }
}
```

Log of 1st test case:

```
Expected $null or empty, but got @({
 "foo": 21,
 "bar": 42
}).
```

Log of 2nd test case:

```
Expected $false, but got $true.
```

Comment: Nicely done; I was going to suggest `Update-TypeData` to create a type-level `.ToString()` override, but it turns out that only works with _explicit_ `.ToString()` calls, and not with casts and string interpolation, which smells like a bug (as of v7.1) - see [GitHub issue #14561](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/14561)

Comment: @mklement0 Another, less hackish way I thought of was to override `Should`, which could cast the input value to a custom `Hashtable` with overridden `.ToString()`, before forwarding it to `Pester\Should`. This seems to be as easy as defining a global `Should` by the test code, but I couldn't get parameter forwarding to work. Possibly worth another question.

Comment: Re parameter forwarding: just in case you're not aware of proxy (wrapper) functions: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55539863/45375. Given that the standard stringification of hashtables is virtually useless, the `Update-TypeData` solution is most appealing to me personally, but that obviously requires a bug fix; if you agree that it should be fixed, I encourage you to give the linked GitHub issue a thumbs-up (they do matter).

Comment: @mklement0 I have upvoted on GitHub. I had tried the proxy wrapper, but running it produced error _"Should: Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters. One or more parameters issued cannot be used together or an insufficient number of parameters were provided."_ -- It looks like the wrapper is missing the [`dynamicparam`](https://github.com/pester/Pester/blob/5bddc0291ae4a05b8a2325940eb1b8607b952cd0/src/functions/assertions/Should.ps1#L120) declaration of `Should`.