# How to create a wrapper for an advanced function cmdlet that uses dynamic parameters

Tags: powershell, wrapper, pester

I'm trying to create a wrapper (proxy) for Pester's [`Should`](https://pester.dev/docs/usage/assertions) cmdlet. Possible use cases include [transparent logging of test input even in case of success](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65490526/7571258) and [improve the way Pester logs objects of certain types, e. g. `hashtable`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65602360/7571258).

As `Should` is an advanced function, forwarding arguments via `$args` splatting does not work.

So I tried to generate a wrapper using `System.Management.Automation.ProxyCommand::Create()`, as described by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55539863/7571258):

```
$cmd = Get-Command Should
$wrapperSource = [System.Management.Automation.ProxyCommand]::Create( $cmd )
$wrapperSource >should_wrapper.ps1
```

When calling the wrapper, Powershell outputs this error message:

> Should: Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named
> parameters. One or more parameters issued cannot be used together or
> an insufficient number of parameters were provided.

It looks like the wrapper generator doesn't understand the [dynamicparam declaration of `Should`](https://github.com/pester/Pester/blob/5bddc0291ae4a05b8a2325940eb1b8607b952cd0/src/functions/assertions/Should.ps1#L120).

How to write a generic wrapper for Pester's `Should` without duplicating Pester code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> It looks like the wrapper generator doesn't understand the dynamicparam declaration of Should.

The wrapper generator *omits* `dynamicparam` by default. Fortunately, this is easily fixed with a bit of templating:

```
$cmd = Get-Command Should
$pct = [System.Management.Automation.ProxyCommand]
$wrapperSource = @(
  $pct::GetCmdletBindingAttribute($cmd)
  'param('
    $pct::GetParamBlock($cmd)
  ')'
  'dynamicparam {'
    $pct::GetDynamicParam($cmd)
  '}'
  'begin {'
    $pct::GetBegin($cmd)
  '}'
  'process {'
    $pct::GetProcess($cmd)
  '}'
  'end {'
    $pct::GetEnd($cmd)
  '}'
) -join [Environment]::NewLine
```

Comment: There is a typo, it should be `param ( ... )`. After fixing that, when calling the wrapper like `0 | .\shouldWrapper.ps1 -Be 1` I get this error message: _"Should: Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters. One or more parameters issued cannot be used together or an insufficient number of parameters were provided."_

Comment: Odd. What version of Pester are you using? It works for me with Pester 3.4 in Windows PowerShell 5.1 and with Pester 5 on PowerShell 7.1

Comment: It failed with Pester 5.0.4 but works with Pester 5.1.1 on both PS versions.

Comment: There is an [overload of `ProxyCommand.Create()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.proxycommand.create?view=powershellsdk-7.0.0#System_Management_Automation_ProxyCommand_Create_System_Management_Automation_CommandMetadata_System_String_System_Boolean_) that has a boolean parameter `generateDynamicParameters`, but doesn't appear to have any effect. Possibly a bug?

Comment: That's my impression, I've never gotten that overload to work - hence the stichwork above :-)

Comment: Nicely done. It is indeed a bug, and it's worth noting that it only affects (advanced) _functions and scripts_, not compiled cmdlets - see [GitHub issue #4792](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/4792); I've added a comment there to point to the workaround here. /cc @zett42

Comment: @zett42, you're right, the bug is still there, and the report should not have been closed. I've left a comment to that effect, with a simpler repro (the original repro was a bit unclear).